# How to replace all theme styles with my own in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a heavy website with a lot of styles. They are being connected with standard wp_enqueue_script()  (in functions.php and some plugins) and hard code (echo '<link ...'). It seems to me that wp_rocket (the best option for optimization I've ever tried) generates critical css not as efficiently as it should be. So, I've decided to create my own css file which I want to load instead of all the others. Is there any plugins or code to replace all style in theme with mine?

Comment: You can use wp_dequeue_script for this

Comment: Have you tried Customise > Appearance > Custom CSS, in the Dashboard? Or are the other CSS links loading later than that one?

Comment: @Ranjit Yeap, but i need to know what style to deregister then. For instance, wp rocket can replace all styles with his own minified files, i`d like to know how.